# Конвертируем объект в JSON с использованием GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world);

    Cat murzik = new Cat();
    murzik.name = "Мурзик";
    murzik.age = 9;
    murzik.color = Color.BLACK;

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    textView.setText(gson.toJson(murzik));
    }
}


public class Cat {

public String name;
public int age;
public int color;


public Cat(){

}
}
```

В результате получаем это

```
{"name":"Мурзик","color":-16777216,"age":9}
```

Подскажите как получить такой результат

```
 {"murzik":[{"name":"Мурзик","color":-16777216,"age":9}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения коллекций эта строка

```
{"murzik":[{"name":"Мурзик","color":-16777216,"age":9}]}
```

описывает хэштаблицу, в которой по ключу `"murzik"` лежит массив/список с вашим объектом.

Т.е. можно положить список с одним котом в хэштаблицу:

```
Map<String, List<Cat>> cats = new HashMap<>();
cats.put("murzik", Arrays.asList(murzik));
textView.setText(gson.toJson(cats));
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых непонятно зачем это делать. Но если делать влоб то нужно сделать еще один класс.

```
class Murzik {
 List<Cat> murzik;
}
```

Но это попахивает бредом. Зачем нужен массив мурзиков?

Comment: Murzik это для примера. Я предполагал что нужно делать через ArrayList<E> но как это сюда подставить? textView.setText(gson.toJson(murzik));

Comment: @qwen может расскажите для чего это нужно? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Мне нужно отправить на сервер информацию. Сервер принимает ее только в таком виде, проблема в том чтобы привести эту информацию к этому виду.

Comment: @qwen значит есть какия-то примера или документация по апи сервера. Можете добавить ее в вопрос?